# Regex for alphanumeric characters plus brackets and spaces

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to build a regex to match these strings:

1. jfldfldf ldjfdlf ldfl
2. ldfldf 8998 dfjldjf 89dfdf dfdf899
3. ljdljf [dff]dfdf (fdfdf) 898

Requirements:

1. String should starts only with any small or capital character (A-Z)
2. It may contain spaces or brackets (`( ) [ ]`)
3. Any other special characters are not allowed

I tried `/^[a-zA-Z]+[\sa-zA-Z0-9\[\]\(\)].+/m`, but it is still accepting other special characters.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So close.

```
/^[a-zA-Z]+[\sa-zA-Z0-9\[\]\(\)].+/m
          ^                     ^ ^-- missing $
          ^                     ^-- delete this dot
          ^-- you could also delete this plus, but that's not as important
```

Answer (score 2):

```
/^[a-zA-Z]{1}[a-zA-Z0-9\ \[\]\(\)]+$/m
```

\s = allows whitespaces like spaces tabs and new lines, so this should probably be "\ "

Because the rule is only the first letter needs to be a capital or lowercase letter, strictly it's {1} as + means one or more.

Needed a $ at the end to show this is the end of the line, and nothing else can follow it

Answer (score 1):

The biggest thing that is failing in that regex is the single '.'. That serves as a wildcard matching any value aside from a new line. The plus symbols are not needed and the end of string character '$' is missing.

```
/^[a-zA-Z][\sa-zA-Z0-9\[\]\(\)]$/m
```

Comment: thank you its also working :) (Y) and i accept @Niet the Dark ans because he answered first ;)